# How do I access these attributes?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, json

I'm going nuts trying to parse get the "name" and "id" attribute of each "division" from this json into a select:

```
[{"division":{"name":"Solo Male","coed":false,"size":1,"created_at":"2009-08-25T16:42:07-04:00","updated_at":"2009-08-25T16:42:07-04:00","id":1}},{"division":{"name":"Solo Female","coed":false,"size":1,"created_at":"2009-08-25T16:42:07-04:00","updated_at":"2009-08-25T16:42:07-04:00","id":2}},{"division":{"name":"4 Person Male","coed":false,"size":4,"created_at":"2009-08-25T16:42:07-04:00","updated_at":"2009-08-25T16:42:07-04:00","id":9}},{"division":{"name":"4 Person Female","coed":false,"size":4,"created_at":"2009-08-25T16:42:07-04:00","updated_at":"2009-08-25T16:42:07-04:00","id":10}},{"division":{"name":"4 Person Coed","coed":true,"size":4,"created_at":"2009-08-25T16:42:07-04:00","updated_at":"2009-10-29T10:46:28-04:00","id":11}},{"division":{"name":"3 Person Male","coed":false,"size":3,"created_at":"2009-08-25T16:42:07-04:00","updated_at":"2009-08-25T16:42:07-04:00","id":6}},{"division":{"name":"3 Person Female","coed":false,"size":3,"created_at":"2009-08-25T16:42:07-04:00","updated_at":"2009-08-25T16:42:07-04:00","id":7}},{"division":{"name":"3 Person Coed","coed":true,"size":3,"created_at":"2009-08-25T16:42:07-04:00","updated_at":"2009-10-29T10:46:22-04:00","id":8}},{"division":{"name":"2 Person Male","coed":false,"size":2,"created_at":"2009-08-25T16:42:07-04:00","updated_at":"2009-08-25T16:42:07-04:00","id":3}},{"division":{"name":"2 Person Female","coed":false,"size":2,"created_at":"2009-08-25T16:42:07-04:00","updated_at":"2009-08-25T16:42:07-04:00","id":4}},{"division":{"name":"2 Person Coed","coed":true,"size":2,"created_at":"2009-08-25T16:42:07-04:00","updated_at":"2009-10-29T10:46:16-04:00","id":5}}]
```

Here's my code that I cannot get to work:

```
jQuery.each(data, function(i,division) {
$('#squad_division').append( $('<option value="'+ division.id+'">'+ division.name +'</option>'));
```

I KNOW I'm just missing something simple where I'm trying to access "division.id" and "division.name" but it eludes me.

Thanks in advance if you can help.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the structure of the JSON you need to change `division.id` to `division.division.id`. Here is a jsfiddle of your *almost* exact same code functioning properly: http://jsfiddle.net/RqwBT/1/

Basically your `division` variable is a single key inside the array (the `data` variable) which is an object, and that object has one property: `division` (which has child-properties that you want to access).

```
jQuery.each(data, function(i,division) {
    $('#squad_division').append( '<option value="'+ division.division.id+'">'+ division.division.name +'</option>');
});
```

Notice I removed the `$()` around the HTML in your append statement as it was creating unnecessary overhead.

I figured this out by calling `console.log(division);` inside the each function which allowed my to inspect a single array key at a time to see how I can access the object's information. This is my standard practice when I am loading JSON from a new source.

Comment: I will get to know jsfiddle TODAY!! Thanks again.

Comment: I'm glad to help. If you are not familiar with a DOM inspection tool like Firebug then I suggest you spend a little time getting to know one, it can save massive amounts of time debugging code.

Answer (score 1):

Aha... your divisions aren't the division *data* yet... they're still an array (containing one division).

You'd need:

```
jQuery.each(data, function(i,data_item) {
    $('#squad_division').append( $('<option value="'+ data_item.division.id+'">'+ data_item.division.name +'</option>'));
```

Comment: No dice. When I use division.id and division.name I am getting option tags added to the select field as expected...I just don't get the attribute values. Instead I get this:

<option value="undefined">undefined</option>

Answer (score 1):

in your code `division` (first one, `data[0]`) is the following object:

```
{
  "division": {
     "name":"Solo Male",
     "coed":false,
     "size":1,
     "created_at":"2009-08-25T16:42:07-04:00",
     "updated_at":"2009-08-25T16:42:07-04:00",
     "id":1
  }
}
```

So you'd need to use `division.division.id` and `division.division.name`